# How do I use node-openid on Heroku with more than one dyno?

Tags: node.js, heroku, openid

I'm trying to use [node-openid](https://github.com/havard/node-openid) (via [passport-google](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google)) to authenticate my users with their Google credentials.  It works fine on my development machine but when I deploy it to Heroku with 2 dynos, it works when one dyno handles the entire OpenID conversation and fails when the conversation is started on one dyno and completed on the second.  In that case I get the following error:

```
2013-01-15T15:18:24+00:00 app[web.2]: Failed to verify assertion (message: Invalid association handle)
2013-01-15T15:18:24+00:00 app[web.2]:     at Strategy.authenticate.identifier (/app/node_modules/passport-google/node_modules/passport-openid/lib/passport-openid/strategy.js:143:36)
...
```

What's the right way to handle this?  Should I be saving the conversation state in a database somehow so that both dynos have access to it?

**Update:**

Here's the code I used to solve the problem by storing the assocation in MongoDB.

```
var
  GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google').Strategy;

// We have to save the OpenID state in the database so it's available to both
// dynos.

db.collection('OpenID').ensureIndex({expires: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 0},
    function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error('Error setting TTL index on OpenID collection.');
        }
    });

// Use the GoogleStrategy within Passport.
//   Strategies in passport require a `validate` function, which accept
//   credentials (in this case, an OpenID identifier and profile), and invoke a
//   callback with a user object.
strategy = new GoogleStrategy({
    returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/return',
    realm: 'http://localhost:3000/'
  },
  function(identifier, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {

      // To keep the example simple, the user's Google profile is returned to
      // represent the logged-in user.  In a typical application, you would want
      // to associate the Google account with a user record in your database,
      // and return that user instead.
      profile.identifier = identifier;
      return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
);

strategy.saveAssociation(function(handle, provider, algorithm, secret, expiresIn, done) {
    db.collection("OpenID").insert({
        handle: handle,
        provider: provider,
        algorithm: algorithm,
        secret: secret,
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * expiresIn)
    }, done);
});

strategy.loadAssociation(function(handle, done) {
    db.collection("OpenID").findOne({handle: handle}, function (error, result) {
        if (error)
            return done(error);
        else
            return done(null, result.provider, result.algorithm, result.secret);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide some details on how you solved this? I am actually using some middleware (passport-google) to do this authentication. Passport is set up to use the Redis store for its sessions. Can you please let me know what you had to do to get this working?

Comment: @electrichead, I added my code above.

Comment: @DavidBraun How exactly do you set `saveAssocation`/`loadAssociation`? What is `strategy` in this context?

Comment: @kynan Code added for your benefit.

Comment: Why are you adding an index to the OpenID collection for "expires" and "expiresIn"? It appears you are fetching the association by "handle". I am just trying to make sure I understand the complete solution here. Also wondering why you are altering the expires value when saving.

Comment: Forget it. I got it. TTL on mongo document. Read the code Kevin! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably check out the [Storing association state](https://github.com/havard/node-openid#storing-association-state) section in the node-openid README. By default, session state is stored in-memory on the individual dynos and that's what's causing you problems.

Override the `saveAssociation()` and `loadAssociation()` mixins to use whatever backing store your application is currently using. There's more [documentation in the passport-openid source code](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-openid/blob/master/lib/passport-openid/strategy.js#L199-L298).